# How to check if element node contains a specific value in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath-2.0

I have an XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<document>
    <fruits>
        <fruit id="1">
            <title>I like pineapples</title>
            <description> a tropical plant with edible multiple fruit consisting of coalesced berries</description>
        </fruit>
        <fruit id="2">
            <title>I like watermelons</title>
            <description>has a smooth exterior rind (green, yellow and sometimes white) and a juicy, sweet interior flesh</description>
        </fruit>
    </fruits>
</document>
```

How do I check if the `title` element contains 'pineapple' so that i can only display `description` for that particular `fruit` ?

Here is the XSLT transformation I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output  method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" doctype-public="-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN"
             doctype-system="http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="html">
      <xsl:element name="head">        
        <xsl:element name="title">Fruits</xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>

      <xsl:element name="body">
        <xsl:if test="/document/fruits/fruit/title[contains(text(),'pineapple')]">
          <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
        </xsl:if>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a predicate like [contains(text(),'pineapple')] for title elements?

Comment: I've tried <xsl:if test="/document/fruis/fruit/title[contains(text(),'pineapple')]">

Comment: In your expression, it should be fruits instead of fruis. And your xml is not well formed, the <fruits> and <fruit> elements are not properly closed. If you fix these, I think it will work.

Comment: @user998692 no, i've corrected the mistakes in xml and <xsl:if> and tested it again but it doesn't work.

Comment: I tested the XPath expression using the tool and it works fine. I think there might be a problem in the XSLT code. Could you show all the related elements in the XSLT?

Comment: @user998692 Please check my XSLT code I've added above. Thanks

Comment: Is the stylesheet correctly linked to the xml?

Comment: I suspect the line <xsl:value-of select="description"/> might be the culprit. Try to put the if in a for-each with a select fruit (the parent of both title and description).

Comment: yes it is correctly linked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a slightly more push-driven approach that accomplishes what you want.

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"
  doctype-public="-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN"
  doctype-system="http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Fruits</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates
          select="fruits/fruit[contains(title, 'pineapple')]" />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fruit">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="description" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied to the provided XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document>
  <fruits>
    <fruit id="1">
      <title>I like pineapples</title>
      <description>a tropical plant with edible multiple fruit
      consisting of coalesced berries</description>
    </fruit>
    <fruit id="2">
      <title>I like watermelons</title>
      <description>has a smooth exterior rind (green, yellow and
      sometimes white) and a juicy, sweet interior
      flesh</description>
    </fruit>
  </fruits>
</document>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Fruits</title>
  </head>
  <body>a tropical plant with edible multiple fruit consisting of coalesced berries</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solution kind of works but it also displays the title and descritpion for watermelon. The result produced is:
a tropical plant with edible multiple fruit consisting of coalesced berries
I like watermelonshas a smooth exterior rind (green, yellow and sometimes white) and a juicy, sweet interior flesh

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using? I've used several (Expat, Saxon, libxslt, etc.) and do not get the results you're seeing.

Comment: Ok Sorry! your solution worked, the solution by @Dimitre Novatchev caused that result.

Comment: @Sujal, Yes, there was a single line missing in my answer, which is now in place.

Answer (score 2):

**A simpler and almost fully "push style" solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Fruits</title>
      </head>
      <body><xsl:apply-templates/></body>
    </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="fruit[contains(title, 'pineapple')]">
  <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<document>
    <fruits>
        <fruit id="1">
            <title>I like pineapples</title>
            <description> a tropical plant with edible multiple fruit consisting of coalesced berries</description>
        </fruit>
        <fruit id="2">
            <title>I like watermelons</title>
            <description>has a smooth exterior rind (green, yellow and sometimes white) and a juicy, sweet interior flesh</description>
        </fruit>
    </fruits>
</document>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

      <title>Fruits</title>
   </head>
   <body> a tropical plant with edible multiple fruit consisting of coalesced berries</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solution kind of works but it also displays the title and descritpion for watermelon. The result produced is:
a tropical plant with edible multiple fruit consisting of coalesced berries
I like watermelonshas a smooth exterior rind (green, yellow and sometimes white) and a juicy, sweet interior flesh

Comment: @Sujal, Sorry, there was a minor copy+paste issue. Corrected now.